# Angular2 get activated route parameters and parent parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

How do I get the RouteParams from a parent component as well as child routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'list', component: UsersComponent },
    {
        path: ':id', component: UserDetailComponent,
        children: [
            // { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'overview', component: UserInfoComponent },
            { path: 'specs/:id', component: UserProfileComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

In component

```
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit { 

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  this.route.parent.params.subscribe( (c) => {
        console.log(c['id']);
    });
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params['id']);
    });
}
}
```

But i am always getting undefined when my route is getting activated . 
kindly help to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Not yet still looking for solution

Comment: For me, I realized I was calling `ActivatedRoute` in a component outside `router-outlet`. That's why I was getting `undefined`. Moving the component to inside `router-outlet` solved my issue.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simple example how to get parameter's value in .ts,
After that you'll be able to customize this to your case

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        const taskId: string = route.snapshot.params["taskId"];
        console.log("this is taskId value = "+ taskId);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

you need ActivatedRouteSnapshot to traverse activated routes.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html

Answer (score 1):

`var myParamValue = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['myParam'];`